# Why @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "home") generates <a href="\">Home</a>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, url-routing

When I use Html.ActionLink, I found that `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "home")` generates this string `<a href="\">Home</a>`, so why the address `\home\index` becomes `\`, I found this is related with default route which setted in web.conf. I have viewed the mvc 3 source code, but I can't find answer. Who can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That's due to the default route. If you don't specify default action and controller it will generate `/home/index` as url.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You can find and change the default route in the Global.asax file

Comment: I think route is to analysis the request url, but ActionLink is to generate a url, not a request from browser, why it is affected with route?

Comment: @avatas, all HTML helpers that work with urls use your route definitions when generating those urls. So they are definitely affected by the routes.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Then I added a new ActionLink @Html.ActionLink("Test1","index", "test1"), the new href string is "\test1", why it is not "\test1\index"? the route only sets the default value of homeControler.I guess the MVC team hate "index".

Comment: @avatas, how does your route look like? I guess you have `action = "index"` default value.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov
<code>routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );</code>

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov OK, so I changed action = "About", then @Html.ActionLink("Test1", "index", "test1") generates '<a href="\test1\index">test1</a>'. I think default parameter is a "And" relationship,but now is is "Or".

Answer (score 2):

routing is bidirectional:
- in: it converts incoming urls into controller/actions/parameters
- out: it converts controller/actions/parameters into urls

Comment: Thanks. So why @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index","home")  = '<a href="\">Index</a>', and @Html.ActionLink("Test1", "Index", "test1") = '<a href="\test1">test1</a>'.

Comment: default values are omitted from the generated url. index is a default value (action) and home is a default value(controller). result: "/". For the second actionlink, test1 is not a default value but index is. result: /test1 (test1 is the controller)